# error: [polling_error] Телеграм бот, необработанная ошибка

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

При отправке контакта пользователя в телеграм боте, появляется ошибка в консоли:

```
error: [polling_error] {}
```

Контакт отправляется, всё работает корректно, все остальные команды отрабатывают, ошибка именно при отправке контакта пользователя.

```
bot.telegramBot.on("message", (msg) => {
const { id } = msg.chat; // decomposition
const { first_name } = msg.from; // decomposition

switch (msg.text.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
  case "/start":
    bot.telegramBot.sendMessage(
      id,
      `${first_name}, Вас приветствует Телеграм Бот - MyClub! Для авторизации необходимо отправить свой номер телефона.`,
      {
        reply_markup: {
          keyboard: [
            [
              {
                text: "Отправить",
                request_contact: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      }
    );
    break;
});
```

Нагуглил, что данная ошибка является необработанной + возможна синтаксическая ошибка, но в чем проблема в данном случае не могу понять. Буду рад любой помощи!

Спасибо!